# Function keeps timing out

Tags: javascript

**This is the problem:**

*Complete the function splitPairs such that it splits the input string into pairs of characters. If the input string has a length that is odd, then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore _. Note, an empty string should make your function produce an empty array.*

**Here is my code (it keeps timing out):**

```
function splitPairs(input) {
  let inputArray = input.split('');
  let result = [];
      
  if (inputArray.length % 2 !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i + 2) {
      let pair = inputArray[i] + inputArray[i+1];
      //push that onto the result array
      result.push(pair);
    }
    result.push(inputArray[inputArray.length - 1] + '_');      
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i + 2) {
      let pair = inputArray[i] + inputArray[i+1];
      result.push(pair);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the proper way to solve this problem? It would be better if I could write the solution myself but I could use help to know what methods I should use to solve it

Comment: It's timing out because you're not incrementing `i`. Change `i + 2` to `i += 2`.

Comment: Also, try doing it without 2 `for` loops. You should only need to modify the last element, the rest will be the same.

Comment: Thank you (y) much appreciated

Comment: @mpen, you should put that as an answer, and Pensive_Knave, you should accept it, because it was first. Drives me up the wall when someone posts the right answer in a comment and then others swoop in trying to get the answer.

Comment: @223seneca it's my first post so I was unaware I could do this but thanks for letting me know

Comment: You can't do it until @mpen posts it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's timing out because you're not incrementing `i`. `i + 2` computes the new value but doesn't assign it anywhere. You can update `i` by doing `i += 2` which is shorthand for `i = i + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment using `i+=2`. Also, there are some mistakes in the solution:

```js
function splitPairs(input) {
  let inputArray = input.split('');
  let result = [];
  if(!inputArray)
    return result;
  if (inputArray.length % 2 !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length-1; i+=2) {
      let pair = inputArray[i] + inputArray[i+1];
      result.push(pair);
    }
    result.push(inputArray[inputArray.length - 1] + '_');    
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i += 2) {
      let pair = inputArray[i] + inputArray[i+1];
      result.push(pair);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(splitPairs(""));

console.log(splitPairs("abcd"));

console.log(splitPairs("abcde"));
```

A simpler solution (with one loop) as mentioned in the comments would be:

```js
function splitPairs(input) {
  let inputArray = input.split('');
  let result = [];
  if(!inputArray)
    return result;
  let odd = (inputArray.length % 2 !== 0);
  let len = (odd) ? inputArray.length-1 : inputArray.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i+=2) {
    let pair = inputArray[i] + inputArray[i+1];
    result.push(pair);
  }
  if(odd)
    result.push(inputArray[inputArray.length - 1] + '_');    
  return result;
}

console.log(splitPairs(""));

console.log(splitPairs("abcd"));

console.log(splitPairs("abcde"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one(two) liner

```
var result=str.split(/(..)/).filter(v=>v)
if (result[result.length-1].length==1) result[result.length-1]+="_"
```

Comment: Although it is nice and clean it does fail one element of the task: `Note, an empty string should make your function produce an empty array.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function splitPairs(input) {
  return input.split('').map((c, i) => {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) return;
    if (input[i+1]) {
      return input[i] + input[i+1];
    }    

    return input[i] + '_';
  }).filter(pair => pair);
}
```